# How do I validate input form field and show error using custom directive in angular material?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-6

I am using reactive forms in Angular Martial 7 and I am trying to validate multiple emails separated by commas in input files, but it shows an error through custom directive. How can I fix this?

Comment: kindly share the stackblitz with a minimal working example

Answer (score 0):

Use angulars FormGroup and define your errors there:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
messageForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
//place your validations here
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  message: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

}